# How is the boolean expression for mux2 and mux4 deduced?

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

I've been looking at the following article: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb_2.html

I am confused as to how the boolean expression Q = a'b'A + ab'B + a'bC + abD is deduced for mux4, and what it would be for mux2. How is it done with kmaps?

Comment: Please post all of the information needed to answer the question in the question body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty intuitive, actually.  Based on the states of a and b, one of the 4 terms of a'b'A + ab'B + a'bC + abD will have a chance of being true.  If ab=00, only the first term can be true, and only if A is true.  If ab=01, then the output is true iff B is true, and so on.

The 2-mux would be a'A + aB.